# Removing Style Attribute in IE6, 8, and Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-6

I'm attempting to work with Javascript through a cross browser platform that is required to support IE6, 8, and Firefox. I've quickly discovered that none of these browsers contain a matching Javascript library.

The goal is to have items that dynamically hide or show depending on the selection of other items. Normally I would just toggle between display:none and display:block but for the work of another developer, I can use the display:none to hide the field, but switching to display:block screws up the layout. The solution is to simply rip out either the display setting in the style, or tear out the style altogether. Unfortunately, I ran into the library problem

Firefox supports everything I've tried so far
IE8 & 6 didn't support getElementById().style.removeProperty('display') 
IE6 doesn't support getElementById().removeAttribute('style')

Below is my code as it currently is, working in IE8 and FF...but it is required to also get it working in IE6.

```
function displayPrevLPQ(bShow) {
    if (bShow) {
        document.getElementById('prevLPQ').removeAttribute('style');
    } else {
        document.getElementById('prevLPQ').style.display = 'none';
    }
}

function displayBusUnitSub() {
    var buVal = document.getElementById('BusinessUnitID').value;
    document.getElementById("BusinessCycle").selectedIndex = document.getElementById("BusinessCycle").getAttribute("default");
    document.getElementById("Ibap").selectedIndex = document.getElementById("Ibap").getAttribute("default");
    document.getElementById("Bca").selectedIndex = document.getElementById("Bca").getAttribute("default");

    switch (buVal) {
        case '11':
            document.getElementById('buSub0').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('buSub1').removeAttribute('style');
            document.getElementById('buSub2').style.display = 'none';
            break;
        case '1':
            document.getElementById('buSub0').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('buSub1').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('buSub2').removeAttribute('style');
            break;
        default:
            document.getElementById('buSub0').removeAttribute('style');
            document.getElementById('buSub1').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('buSub2').style.display = 'none';
            break;
    }
}
```

So, the question is...how can I tear out the Style or display properties in a way that will work across all three browsers?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I really pity anyone who has to work with IE6 these days.  :-(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a javascript library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) that already has all the browser compatibility issues sorted and abstracted away.

From the [docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Browser_compatibility) it appears to support everything you need:

> jQuery supports these browsers:

```
* Firefox 2.0+
* Internet Explorer 6+
* Safari 3+
* Opera 9+
* Chrome 1+
```

As for the specific jQuery function to to this - look at [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).

Comment: Although it's possible (depending on your requirement for 'legacy' support) that the [BBC's Glow library](http://www.bbc.co.uk/glow/) might be a good fit. I've not used it, but its entire reason for being was the BBC's need to support browsers back to IE 5.5.

Comment: What kind of answer is this? At least point the OP to the appropriate jQuery method, which I'm not sure even exists.

Comment: @Oded: That was me. I didn't think you answered the question, as I somewhat rudely said. You've improved it massively now: not being a jQuery user, I was not aware of the `toggle()` method, which does appear to do exactly what's asked.

Comment: @Oded: It seems I downvoted after your edit (which I didn't see), so I've had to edit your answer (I deleted one invisible line break) before I could undo my downvote.

Comment: @Tim Down - no problem. I originally figured that `toggle` was so basic to jQuery it didn't need mentioning (as any look at jQuery would find it). You were quite right (if not entirely polite...) to point out that this may not be the case...

Comment: @Oded: I'm not very tolerant of answers that simply say "Use jQuery! It rocks!", which is what I initially took yours for. Sorry.

Comment: @Tim Down - no hard feelings... Learning is also about how people perceive ones answers... Teaches me to provide better answers and more examples :)

Answer (score 0):

> ...required to support IE6, 8, and Firefox. I've quickly discovered that none of these browsers contain a matching Javascript library.

[jQuery](http://jquery.com), [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), and [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/) all support those three browsers (and more). I expect [many of these others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries) do as well. [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library) doesn't (at least, it doesn't claim to and we know Google dropped IE6 support in most of its products), but it's the first major library I know of to wave bye-bye to IE6.

Answer (score 0):

Use a class instead. If you only use one class on your element, it's as simple as this:

CSS:

```
*.hidden {
   display: none;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
function show(el) {
    el.className = "";
}

function hide(el) {
    el.className = "hidden";
}

show(document.getElementById("foo"));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can still toggle between display:block/none;
target the IEs via conditional comments or IE specific hacks to fix your layout issues.
so lets say that you have width set on id uSub0 of 200px. and its breaking in IEs, you need it to be 190px for them. heres how you can target them. example:

## uSub0{width:200px}

/** ie6 only **/

## uSub0{width:200px; *width:190px}

/** ie7 only **/

## uSub0{width:200px}

*:first-child+html #uSub0{width:190px}
/** ie7 only **/

## uSub0{width:200px}

*+html #uSub0{width:190px}
/** ie6, ie7, ie8 **/

## uSub0{width:200px; width: 190px\9}

/** ie7, ie8 **/

## uSub0{width:200px; width/***/: 190px}